# Can't match password values in bcrypt when comparing in laravel

Tags: passwords, laravel-5

Hey guys I'm trying to set up a change password feature where the user can change his own password by knowing the courrent password.The problem stands when I compare the values to match the passwords they don't eaven though I enter the same values.I insert users prom the panel with a default value in the password filed which is the **bcrypted** value of *'admin1234'* .When I login with this password everything is ok.Then I go to the change password field...retrive the password from the form...encrypt it and than compare it...it turns out its a different value...I eaven *echo*-ed them and in deed they are a different values...am I missing something here ??

Update Password function :

```
public function change_password(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $this->validate($request, array(
            'courrent_password'=>'required|max:255',
            'new_password'=>'required|max:255'
        ));

        $user = User::find($id);
        if($user->password == bcrypt($request->courrent_password))
        {
            /*$user->password = $request->new_password;

            if($user->save())
            {
                return  redirect(route('user_profile',$id))->with('success', sprintf('Password successfully saved.'));}
            else if ($validation->fails())
            {
                return redirect(route('user_profile',$id.'#tab_1-3'));
            }*/
        }
        else
        {
            echo bcrypt($request->courrent_password).'  new password';
            echo'<br><br>'.$user->password.' password';
            //return redirect(route('user_profile',$id.'#tab_1-3'))->with('error', sprintf("Current password doesn't match"));
        }
    }
```

Update password form :

```
{!! Form::open(array('route' =>  ['change_password',$user-> id],'id' => 'form_sample_2','class'=>'form-horizontal','novalidate' => 'novalidate','role' => 'form')) !!}
                                        {!! csrf_field() !!}
                                        <div class="form-body">
                                            <div class="alert alert-danger display-hide">
                                                <button class="close" data-close="alert"></button> You have some form errors. Please check below. </div>
                                            <div class="alert alert-success display-hide">
                                                <button class="close" data-close="alert"></button> Your form validation is successful! </div>
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label class="control-label col-md-3">Courrent Password
                                                    <span class="required" aria-required="true"> * </span>
                                                </label>
                                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                                    <input type="password" name="courrent_password" data-required="1" id="courrent_password" class="form-control">
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label class="control-label col-md-3">New Password
                                                    <span class="required" aria-required="true"> * </span>
                                                </label>
                                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                                    <input type="password" name="new_password" data-required="1" id="password" class="form-control">
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label class="control-label col-md-3">Retype Password
                                                    <span class="required" aria-required="true"> * </span>
                                                </label>
                                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                                    <input type="password" name="repassword" data-required="1" id="repassword" class="form-control" onkeyup="checkPass(); return false;">
                                                    <span class="help-block" id="checkpass"></span>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-actions">
                                            <div class="row">
                                                <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-9">
                                                    <button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn green">Submit</button>
                                                    <button type="button" class="btn grey-salsa btn-outline">Cancel</button>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        {!! Form::close() !!}
```

this are the results echo-ed

```
$2y$10$2S/6BBrBdxe9FHzjH33g0elCgjUov4Pq7EBkRwE.n2JkbvCwHXPFC new password

$2y$10$55V3ZfdbDOutDUZKO3q6nezntlQqYqqiyhVhwTPEnWuZmy.8/QxYG password
```

Answer (score 0):

use this :

```
if(Auth::attempt(['email' =>Auth::user()->email, 'password'=>$request['courrent_password']]))
```

instead of this :

```
if($user->password == bcrypt($request->courrent_password))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not match two bcrypt values. use **Hash :: check ()** method
     public function changePassword(changePasswordValidator $request)
       {
           $password = $request->password;
           $person_id = $request->person_id;
           $sub = Subadmin::find($person_id);
            if(Hash::check($password, $sub->subadmin_password)) {
                return response()->json([
                'status'=>false,
                'message'=>'Similar to Old Password',
            ]);
          }
            $sub->subadmin_password = bcrypt($password);
            $sub->save();
         }